# Matched Geometry Effect: Card View Expanding

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I'm trying to create a view where cards with different subscriptions are displayed, and when you toggle, they expand to show details. I want the animation of one card to smoothly affect others, seamlessly shifting them.

Here is the result I have achieved so far

[image]

And that's my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var toogle1: Bool = false
    @State private var toogle2: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    subscriptionCurrentYearView()
                    subscriptionPreviousYearView()
                }
                .padding(16)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func subscriptionCurrentYearView() -> some View {
        SubscriptionView(toggleOn: $toogle1)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func subscriptionPreviousYearView() -> some View {
        SubscriptionView(toggleOn: $toogle2)
    }
}

struct SubscriptionView: View {
    @Namespace private var animation
    @Binding var toggleOn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("I want to subscribe this product from the current year")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .frame(width: 250, alignment: .leading)
                Toggle("", isOn: $toggleOn)
                    .frame(width: 50)
            }
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Header", in: animation)
            .padding()
            
            if toggleOn {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Estimated current balance")

                    TextField("", text: .constant("$ 0.00"))
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Your whole amount must be transferred for the current tax year")
                }
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Content", in: animation)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(Color(uiColor: UIColor.lightGray))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        .animation(.linear, value: toggleOn)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

As you can see, the animation is jittery and doesn't look good. I tried using matchedGeometryEffect, but it doesn't seem to change anything - I'm probably doing it wrong. Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to use `.matchedGeometryEffect` for this. Instead, you just need to change the way the binding is used so that the animation has a wider impact.

Change the toggle to this:

```swift
Toggle("", isOn: $toggleOn.animation())
```

then comment out the `.matchedGeometryEffect`, the `.animation` modifier and the redundant namespace.

Like this:

```swift
struct SubscriptionView: View {
//    @Namespace private var animation
    @Binding var toggleOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("I want to subscribe this product from the current year")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .frame(width: 250, alignment: .leading)
                Toggle("", isOn: $toggleOn.animation())
                    .frame(width: 50)
            }
//            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Header", in: animation)
            .padding()

            if toggleOn {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Estimated current balance")

                    TextField("", text: .constant("$ 0.00"))
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Your whole amount must be transferred for the current tax year")
                }
//                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Content", in: animation)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(Color(uiColor: UIColor.lightGray))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
//        .animation(.linear, value: toggleOn)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]